How to make the Python terminal on VScode only show the output
I have just recently get into Python programming. In the YouTube videos I've watched, every time they run a Python program, the VS Code terminal only show the output.
In my VS Code, it also shows two windows' directories first before showing the output, which I'd rather not have. Below is my code on the computer screen:
PS C:\Users\Bill\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence> &
C:/Users/Bill/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "c:/Users/Bill/Desktop/Artificial Intelligence/Day 1 - Self-taught Py/snake.py"
1

Is there any way I could make VS Code only show the output?

If you will allow be to be a curmudgeon, VSCode is just an editor and development environment.  Whatever its quirks are, you will NEVER actually use it to deploy your final product, so end users are never going to see what you see.  Your life may be easier if you learn to live with it.

Hi, if you want to set up the test file, you can go to the settings by using the shortcut Ctrl+,. By setting up a python extension, for example though python.testing.cwd set the options. If you want to run general code, you can refer to the answer below and try adding a task to configure.


Ensure python is installed
To check that, open VS code, go to extension by pressing ctlr+shift+X and search for python and ensure it is installed.



Open command palette by pressing ctrl+shift+p and type tasks.

Select Tasks: configure tasks, then choose Create tasks.json file from template then choose other as the template.

Modify the tasks.json file with following content
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Run Python File",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "python",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "echo": false,
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared"
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]



Run the Task: To run the Python file using this task, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type Run Task. Select Run Python File.


